# Tkinter - Can I use multiple after functions without them interfering?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a clicker game using python. I'm using tkinter for the GUI. I'm trying to use .after function inside of functions to add an integer to a total number. I have it set up so it adds 1 every second which works fine. I am trying to do this with multiple functions adding 5,10,15 per second. The after function works fine until more than one is going at a time. Once there is multiple the time speeds up and it adds every fraction of a second once they start adding up.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("800x700")  #makes the window size 900x700
window.resizable(0, 0)  #make it so window cannot be resized

total = 0
def addone():
    global total
    total = total + 1
    add = window.after(1000, addone)
    print(total)

button = tk.Button(command=addone, width=10, height=10)
button.grid(column=1, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Every time the button is clicked the total adds up faster and faster. I can't seem to find a way make it stop this. I am trying to make it add by 1 every second then after the button is clicked add by 2 every second and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question try it like this:

This will make it so when you click the button it will add 1 and next time it will add 1+1 and the next time it will add 1+2 etc:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("800x700")  #makes the window size 900x700
window.resizable(0, 0)  #make it so window cannot be resized

total = 0
number = 1
def addone():
    global total
    total = total + number
    number = number + 1
    add = window.after(1000, addone)
    print(total)

button = tk.Button(command=addone, width=10, height=10)
button.grid(column=1, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

If you want it to multiply instead of adding do it like this:

```
import thinker as to

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("800x700")  #makes the window size 900x700
window.resizable(0, 0)  #make it so window cannot be resized

total = 0
number = 1
def addone():
    global total
    total = total + number
    number = number * 1
    add = window.after(1000, addone)
    print(total)

button = tk.Button(command=addone, width=10, height=10)
button.grid(column=1, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Sorry if that want what you meant but if you could explain it better it would help a lot!

Comment: That's not exactly what I was looking for. What I'm trying to do is to have it add x to the total every second where x is the number of times the button has been clicked. So if the button was clicked once it would just print 1,2,3,4 ect. Then if the button is clicked again then it would add 2 to the total every second so then it would print 6,8,10,12 then if clicked again and again it would keep adding.

Comment: I'm not used to thinker so could you just explain me is this the seconds it takes to loop? `add = window.after(1000, addone)`

Comment: Yes that function, after 1000 milliseconds (1 second) will execute the addone function. I think the problem is that when the button is pressed more than once it starts executing more than once a second which is not what I want to happen.

Comment: Try removing it from the function!

Comment: It has to be in the function to loop every second

Comment: Its because you have total +1 and evry time you click it adds one so try to make another function that executes once and loops onother function! If you need I will do my best to demonstrate!